# Shift elements in a linked list in java

Tags: java, linked-list, shift, doubly-linked-list, circular-list

I have to shift all of the tokens left by one position in a Linked List.

Here's my code for the method:

```
private LLNode<E> head;     // the first node in the list
private LLNode<E> tail;     // the last node in the list

public void shiftLeft()
{
    LLNode<E> temp = new LLNode<E>();
    temp = head;
    head = head.next;
    tail.next = temp;
}

/*from main method
TopSpinLinkedList<Integer> ll = new TopSpinLinkedList<Integer>(numTokens, spinSize);

//fills LinkedList with tokens
for(int i = 1; i <= numTokens; i++) {
    ll.add(i);
}
*/
```

A nullpointer error appears during runtime when I call the method.  Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What is head in your code?

Comment: first node in the list

Comment: Either `head` or `tail` must be `null`. Without more code (a complete runnable program with the minimal amount of code that reproduces the problem always helps), it's impossible for us to tell which.

Comment: You are having circular linkedList?

Comment: Can you show us your full code? Like where you initializing head and tail.

Comment: Then, only changing the position of head and tail is going to be enough if you structured your list truely. `head = head.next; tail = tail.next`

Comment: @user2280464 probably the bug is in the initialization of `head` or `tail`, not in the code you provided.

Comment: By the way, you do not need to create a new LLNode.

Comment: Could you give your add method too?

Comment: I guess, your problem is solved

Answer (score 1):

If it is circular linked list and your add method works properly.

```
public void shiftLeft(){
    head = head.next; tail = tail.next;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to think about some points: 
1) If your link list does not contain any element then what?
2) For all tokens to be shifted you have to use while-loop.

Comment: 2 is not true. You only need to change the head, we're not talking about an array.

Comment: You don't need a while loop - this is a linked list we are talking about. Moving the head should be enough.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that `head` and `tail` are properly updated on `insert` and `remove`

```
public void shiftLeft()
{
    if(head == null || head.next == null){
       return;    
    }
    LLNode<E> temp = new LLNode<E>();     
    temp = head;           
    head = head.next;  
    temp.next = null;   
    tail.next = temp;  
    tail = temp;  
}
```

**UPDATE:**
From the comment I see that the OP mentions about a circular list. This is not mentioned in the OP or apparent from the code. I will leave the answer as is.

Comment: nullpointer exception still appears after trying this. does this mean I didn't adjust my add() and remove() methods correctly?

Comment: Yes.I suspect you don't update the `tail`.You should make `head=tail=node` in a single element list.

Comment: is there anyway you can show me how to do shiftRight() as well?

Comment: this results in shifting left :/